# A song in episode 2 of GitS: Stand Alone Complex

Tags: music, ghost-in-the-shell

I'm looking for music that sounds in the background on the second episode of *GitS: Stand Alone Complex*, the episode with the rogue tank. The music is playing from 11:35 to 15:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The track you're looking for is:

```
Album                       : Ghost in the Shell - Stand Alone Complex - OST - Be Human
Track name                  : spotter
Track name/Position         : 9
Performer                   : YOKO KANNO
Recorded date               : 2003
```